# Angular JS and Oauth 2.0 Integration

Tags: javascript, angularjs, django, oauth, oauth-2.0

I want to integrate Oauth 2.0 authentication with my angularJS app with my own Oauth 2.0 provider (no facebook etc for now). I will build the backend API with django restful framework, but for now I'm creating the front end.

Basically, what I need to do is :

1. Basic form to login a user with my own Oauth 2.0 server
2. When a user requests "/", I want to be able to check if he's authenticated. If yes : loading the privatePage Template, if no : loading the login template. (or redirecting to "/login")

I found that library : https://github.com/seegno/angular-oauth2 but it doesn't seem to cover the specific part above in the readme documentation.

I am looking everywhere to do it but with no chance, I'm wondering if I am taking this the wrong way.

PS : I am not planning on using a BaaS.

Answer (score -1):

I have never tried but you can do this

**https://github.com/harshdoshi999/angular-oauth2**

Comment: This is just a fork of the same link I put in my question !